# jQuery on click function not working after appending list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple click event using the `on` function:

```
$('#listnav li').on({
    click: function(event) {
        console.log('hello world')              
    }, 
    mouseover: function(event) {
        // do something
    }

});
```

This is working for the ul list with id "listnav". But when I am adding new entries to the ul using jQuery's `append` function, this function is not called on the new added list items. How can I fix this?

Comment: $('#listnav').on('click', 'li', function(){  .....  });

Comment: Does seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/upf0pddh/ I don't usually use this syntax for an on function

Comment: The difference between their code and mine is that I don't use quotes, so I should it looks like in my situation?

Comment: @lharby By adding return false to the end of the click function is not working for me.

Comment: It would be good if you could make an mvce https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve maybe there is something else going on in the code? What is your append function? And can you add the html to your question

Comment: You can use like this https://jsfiddle.net/kLbrngo5/ @Caspert

Comment: It's working, `dynamicli` is being added and when you click on the new li it is returning (event.target.innerHTML) in the console.

Comment: @lharby Do you have a link? Previous link is the same as before.

Comment: I updated the same fiddle adding a console.log to prove the function was working after dynamic elements had been added.

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced same issue,

While you dynamically append anything (here you are adding new entries to `ul`), you need to bind its event too. as event is already binded when DOM is loaded and the `append` is made later on. You need to define the click function within the function of `Append` after your required append is done.

Hope this helps.